# BOOST ASIO и сигнатура callback при вызове асинхронных операций чтения\записи\коннекта сокета

Tags: c++, asio

Собственно безопасно ли использовать в boost::asio::async_connect connect_handler с такой сигнатурой:

```
void (boost::system::error_code&, Iterator)
```

То есть с boost::system::error_code является ссылкой, а не самим объектом.
Ессно это касается и других похожих функций(async_resolve, async_write и тп)

Comment: Документация недвусмысленно требует принимать `boost::system::error_code const &`

Comment: А можно ссылку? А то я смотрю на сигнатуры и там код ошибки передается не как ссылка. Понятно что const& может держать rvalue, но у меня с++03

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect/overload2.html кусок `the function signature of the completion handler must be:`